# Best automatic test framework for octave

Tags: matlab, tdd, bdd, octave, xunit

Which is the best framework for automatic testing in octave?

Why?

Comment: I don't know of any frameworks for automatic testing in Octave so I can't tell you which is the best.  But if you had asked about Matlab I think the answer might be the MATLAB xUnit Test Framework.  I wonder whether you could tweak it to work with Octave, in the absence of any Octave-specific frameworks.

Comment: Like Mark, I'm not aware of any frameworks for Octave, but since it's FOSS, you're welcome to build one! =0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use MatLab or Octave, but it looks like [Appendix A](http://octave.sourceforge.net/coda/a1393.html#sect-ex-unittest) of [this document](http://octave.sourceforge.net/coda/index.html) ([also available as PDF](http://octave.sourceforge.net/coda/coda.pdf)) might be a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Might not be the best one, but it comes with the base install: [Test Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Test-Functions.html)